# ASP.NET Core 6 Session Idle Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, model-view-controller, web-deployment-project

I'm trying to access the idle timeout from the session on razor view. I want to get the time in the idle timeout property (e.g.20 minutes) then when the time idle hits 18 minutes open a modal popup that will have a timer counting down from 2 minutes.

I have the popup modal already working but the 20 minutes is hard coded in. I rather it grab the total time from the idle timeout in the session for future proofing.

Comment: Can you share your sample code?

Answer (score 1):

`idle-time out` refers to the parameter in `applicationhost.config`, which refers to the fact that the site will go to sleep for 20 minutes after there are no requests. When a new request comes in, the site will be activated. It different with session timeout.

Session timeout refers to the browser does not interact with the IIS server, after 20min, the default current user is disconnected from the server and needs to log in again.